# Библиотека matplotlib: построение графика функции |y| = x^2 - 2x - 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, математика, matplotlib, графики

Всем привет. Как построить график для функции |y| = x^2-2x-3? График должен выглядеть вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При выполнении данного кода выводится неправильный график.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(-40, 40, 10000)
y = x ** 2 - 2 * x - 3
plt.figure(1)
plt.title('График функции |y| = x^2 - 2x - 3')
plt.ylabel('Ось y')
plt.xlabel('Ось x')
plt.grid()
plt.axis([-10, 16, 0, 10]) 
plt.plot(x, np.abs(y))
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста как его исправить?

Comment: ты выводишь график другой функции. А именно  ``y = |x^2 - 2x - 3|``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(-40, 40, 10000)
y = x ** 2 - 2 * x - 3
ind = y >= 0
x1 = x[ind]
y1 = y[ind]
x2 = x[~ind]
y2 = y[~ind]
plt.figure(1)
plt.title('График функции |y| = x^2 - 2x - 3')
plt.ylabel('Ось y')
plt.xlabel('Ось x')
plt.grid()
plt.axis([-10, 16, -10, 10]) 
plt.scatter(x1, y1, s = 1, c = 'b')
plt.scatter(x1, -y1, s = 1, c= 'b')
plt.plot(x2, y2, 'r--')
plt.plot(x2, -y2, 'r--')
plt.show()
```

Вывод:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надеюсь, из кода всё понятно, но немного поясню.

Поскольку `|y|` может быть только больше нуля, нам нужно выделить значения функции, которые >= 0 и нарисовать в основной части графика только их. Для этого мы делаем булевую маску для всех значений `f(x)` (в моём коде это значение обозначено как `y`, но мой `y` это не `y` из вашей формулы).

```
ind = y >= 0
```

Более понятно можно записать так:

```
ind = (y >= 0)
```

В `ind` у нас теперь булева маска, содержащая `True` на тех позициях, где `y >= 0` и `False`, где `y < 0`.

Далее, мы отбираем по этой маске значения из наших массивов `x` и `y`:

```
x1 = x[ind]
y1 = y[ind]
```

А также мы отбираем остальные значения `x` и `y`, для чего инвертируем маску с помощью булевой операции инверсии `~` (где было `True` станет `False` и наоборот:

```
x2 = x[~ind]
y2 = y[~ind]
```

После этого мы рисуем основной график, причём два раза - один раз используя `f(x)`, а другой раз `-f(x)` (по формуле `|y| = f(x)` получается, что у нас есть два графика: `y = f(x)` и `y = -f(x)`).

И затем рисуем псевдо-график там, где функция `f(x)` могла бы продолжаться, но из-за условия равенства модулю `|y|` она в этом месте прерывается.

Comment: Что означает кусок кода с `ind = y >= 0` по `y2 = y[~ind]`?

Comment: @Klef Немного расписал, но не уверен, что стало понятнее )

Comment: Понял, спасибо.